# image not saving at an particular location

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save an image in a specific path. The code is executing successfully without any errors but I am not able to see the saved image in my directory.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('G:\pics\My Post.jpg')

cv2.imwrite(r'E:\Python programs\Banking Project\image.png',img)

cv2.imshow('Original',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As @jean mentioned:[Ipython cv2.imwrite() not saving image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136070/ipython-cv2-imwrite-not-saving-image)

I also tried his approach and it did not help me.

Would any of you be kind enough to help me?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried and the image you want to save?

Comment: posted the code.  image I have randomly taken a picture from my directory

Comment: Could try to save the image as JPG format?

Comment: is your `imshow()` displaying any image ?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Tried using JPG format but did not work!

Comment: @YashKumarAtri yes...it is showing me the image.

Comment: `cv2.imwrite('image.png',img)`, If it fails then provide system info and python env and version of cv2

Comment: @YashKumarAtri It is solved Yash. There are some spaces in the folder path. That should not be the case it seems. I tried giving a different location which has no spaces between them and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid space in-between folder path

```
E:\Python programs\Banking Project\image.png
```

Comment: The folder path has spaces. That is the reason why I had given spaces.

Comment: I tried giving the path without spaces and it worked. Thanks