# cv2.error:(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, python-3.x

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Reference code:

http://blog.tramvm.com/2017/05/recognize-text-from-image-with-python.html

this is the python code for extracting text from an image

when i tried to run the code i am getting the above mentioned error

CODE:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Path of working folder on Disk
src_path = "C:\\Users\\preetha\\PycharmProjects\\OCR"

def get_string(img_path):
# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Convert to gray
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# Write image after removed noise
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

#  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

# Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

# Remove template file
#os.remove(temp)

return result


print ("--- Start recognize text from image ---")
print (get_string(src_path + "1.png"))

print ("------ Done -------")
```

I also tried by changing the path directories to '/' or '\'  still not getting any results...
Any solutions please?

Comment: The filename is wrong.  Confusingly, `cv2.imread()` does NOT throw an exception if it can't read the file.  It just returns None instead of an actual image, which then causes problems later on when you try to work with the image.

Answer (score 0):

### Please check:

1. If the image exists in the path provided
2. If the image is loaded correctly by printing

Try printing `img_path`

I suppose the `src_path = "C:\\Users\\preetha\\PycharmProjects\\OCR\\"`

Comment: it's most likely because of the file path, look  at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136150/11745574)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use

```
os.path.join(src_path , "1.jpg")
```

than it is to use

```
src_path+"1.jpg"
```

If the path contains non-ASCII characters, you couldn't load the image (for example, if in the path you have `toña`, you'll get a 215 error).