# Processed image using openCV but can't save changes as a new image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this simple code that reads in an image

`image = cv2.imread(input_path)`

Then changes the color to gray

`image_corrected = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

I can actually display the new gray image to my Jupyter notebook output

`plt.imshow(img_corrected)`

However, when I try to write the changes as a new image, the changes don't appear in the image i.e the image is still colored instead of gray.

`cv2.imwrite(new_image_path, image_corrected)`

I have tried to upgrade my openCV library but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136070/ipython-cv2-imwrite-not-saving-image/40136150

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that the **directory exists**. If you wish to convert RGB image to Grayscale in OpenCV, there is a simpler way.

1. Check if the directory exist, just create one if doesn't exists

```py
import os

check_dir = os.path.split(new_image_path)[0]
if not os.path.isdir(check_dir):
    os.mkdir(check_dir)
```

2. Read the image as grayscale

```py
img_gray = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)
```

3. Save it immediately

```py
cv2.imwrite(new_image_path, img_gray)
```